# SQL to find records that don't have a type of record in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write some SQL that queries two tables and brings back records that doesn't have a particular type of record in the other table.

If table 1 is an employee table that has EmpID, name, surname.

and the 2nd table is a bookings table that has Booking ID, EmpID, year

I want to find all records where there are no bookings for 2014.

so if the employee table is:

```
EMPID   Name   Surname

1        John   Doe
2        Bob    Smith
```

and the Booking table is

```
Booking ID   Emp ID   Year
1             1        2013
2             1        2014
3             2        2012
4             2        2013
```

I want the sql to only

Comment: Thank you for your help as always!! as soon as I posted it and went back to SQL manager I relaised I was breing stupid and querying on the booking ID when I want to be removing all of the Employee ID's and not booking IDs!! THANKS!!!

Comment: @Abraham `@Comments` are the best way.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT * FROM employee
 LEFT JOIN Booking ON Booking.empid = employee.empid AND year = 2014
 WHERE Booking.empid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WHERE` clause with a `NOT EXISTS` check to filter the records you require:

```
SELECT e.EMPID, e.[Name], e.Surname
FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT EmpID 
       FROM Booking b 
       WHERE b.BookingId = e.EmpId and b.Year = 2014)
```

### [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73dea/2)

For reference, here's the SQL Fiddle create / insert script:

```
create table employee(EMPID int, Name varchar(50), Surname varchar(50))
create table booking(BookingID int, EmpID int, Year int)

insert into employee (EMPID, Name, Surname) values(1,'John','Doe')
insert into employee (EMPID, Name, Surname) values(2,'Bob','Smith')

insert into booking(BookingID,EmpID,Year) values(1,1,2013)
insert into booking(BookingID,EmpID,Year) values(2,1,2014)
insert into booking(BookingID,EmpID,Year) values(3,2,2012)
insert into booking(BookingID,EmpID,Year) values(4,2,2013)
```

Comment: This won't work.  He wants to do the opposite of what an Inner Join will do.

Comment: Way to include a SQL Fiddle.  That is great.

Answer (score 2):

One often over looked solution is EXCEPT. This is SQL server specific syntax and is basically the opposite of a UNION

```
SELECT 
       e.EMPID,
       e.Name,
       e.Surname
FROM
      employee e
EXCEPT
SELECT 
       e.EMPID,
       e.Name,
       e.Surname
FROM
      employee e 
      INNER JOIN Booking B
      ON e.empID = b.empid
WHERE
       b.year = 2014
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f690/2)

Another also overlooked syntax is `!= ANY` the major difference between that and NOT IN is that you don't have to worry about null empId in booking

```
SELECT 
       EmpId, Name 
FROM   employee e
WHERE  empid != ANY (SELECT empid 
                     FROM   booking 
                     WHERE  year = 2014)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2579/14)

Comment: Great way of approaching it. Should be natural to anyone who loves their Venn diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from employee
   where empid not in
   (select empid from Booking
        where year = 2014)
```

Illustrative only, of course, "select *" generally isn't a good thing, better to return the columns you specifically want...

If your Booking table contains null EmpIds, however, you could cater for it with something like this:

```
select * from employee
   where empid not in
   (select empid from Booking
        where year = 2014 and empid is not null)
```

Comment: Regarding your note, you may want to look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91558/148672) on meta.se for possible alternatives

Comment: @Anon, you've put a null empid in the Booking table to cause this to break. That wasn't indicated in the OPs scenario. Nonetheless, in the interests of completeness, I've updated my answer to address this as well.

Comment: @ConradFrix - thanks, I wasn't aware of that page, interesting to see the debate. The way I read it, I think I'm okay, the accepted answer suggests it's appropriate to suggest to the OP to replace the asterisk with appropriate fields? Certainly when I deal with my assocs, I'd prefer to give them a gentle nudge on things like this to encourage them to think about it themselves. Appreciate the link and heads up though.

Comment: @PulseLab solutions that break easily or have surprising side effects are bad solutions.  There are robust alternatives (`NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN`, `EXCEPT`)

Comment: @PulseLab what your was absolutely fine and didn't mean to suggest otherwise. Also I would have written `where year = 2014 and empid is not null` rather than `isnull` just to avoid the possiblity that someone get's clever and uses -1 as an actual empid

Comment: @ConradFrix you're absolutely right, using a magic number there was sucky. I blame the lateness of the hour here! Thanks, edited to that better option!